# React Native Expo Timout Error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm currently trying to learn react native. I created a project using create-react-native-app. After the project is created, I started npm start on the folder which shows the QR code. I've installed the expo app on my android phone and scanned the code but I'm getting a **Uncaught Error: Timed out, no manifest in cache** on my expo app and there is no stack trace given.

I've made it work a while ago but somehow its currently not working.

Im using windows 10.
npm 5.6
yarn 1.5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that causes this is having multiple network connections. In my case, I have a virtual network connection which is used by the packager instead of the wifi connection. So basically what's happening is that my phone and my computer uses different connections. I've found a solution here: https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/598

Answer (score 2):

What I've done to fix it using Ubuntu was (I created my app using create-react-native-app):

1. open terminal
2. execute `ifconfig`
3. find network interface (wlp4s0, in my case)
4. execute `export REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME="IP_FOUND_BEFORE"`
5. yarn start
6. SUCCESS! `Finished building JavaScript bundle in 10069ms`

Answer (score 0):

Expo only supports the most recent 6 versions, this is because we have to have all the native code for each version on the client and that gets big fast . As of writing this v26 is almost out, that version of the expo client will not support v19 projects. Please make sure that your app is up-to-date by going to the `app.json` (or `exp.json` depending on how old your project is ) and checking the version number.

Outside of that, I would also recommend you start your project by calling `exp start` in the root folder of your project

Comment: Im trying it in a fresh new project. Basically what I did was follow react-native's guide which is install create-react-native-app, use the command to create a project, go to the folder, run npm start, scan the QR code and I get the error. I think the create-react-native-app installs updated versions.

Comment: i too stuck in same place, did you got the solution for it? @Dujndaf

Comment: @KhanStan99 I found a solution to my problem here: https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/598